# side story breaking off from my main one about side character?

Tags: novel, characters

Just a general question, but would anyone actually read a side story to my main novel about a side character?

He plays a big role in the story actually, but he doesn't get much recognition in the book because it would stray from the plot if I wrote him in with detail.

Comment: I would write it, if not for your readers than just to flesh out the character and have some fun. Maybe think of it as a fanfiction-like exploration of your world and characters rather than a seperate big project.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I really want the readers to know just how important this character is to the plot.

Comment: JKR is writing the screenplays for a whole movie saga about a character that is hardly mentioned in the Harry Potter books. In Terry Pratchett's Disc World, all main characters are side characters in other instalments of the series. So yes, if your world and characters sell well, I believe you can write about side characters.

Comment: @Filip Thanks, that gives me more reasons to write this story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all good and bad in this world, it depends on the context of you story and your side character in question.

**Is it funny?, Is it interesting? Does it give something extra, that is importan for you to tell in the story? Do other people whant to see it?**

If most of that questions are yes, then maybe (just maybe), it will be a good idea to make more strories about the side character, as many have said, some side characters steal the show because how interesting they seem, and we whant to know more of them.

Or maybe they past is some how important to our current situation, (just ask the prequels of Star Wars that are made to explain who Dark Vader is).

*At the end, if you are not interesting in the story of said character, and you are only writing more and more random thought over a character that you don´t actually care, the result of not doing something you care or love is ofter pure **garbage.***

If **YOU** think you should doit, go ahead, if you can make that character improve and mean something more to your story that just being a face in the background, sure then, go ahead.

At the end, the choice is yours, ***but you must make it.***

Comment: Man, my story is definitely happening, then.

Comment: Aspen Rand, can I ask you then to mark my answer as the good one?, I still need some privilege for my almost-new profile.

Answer (score 1):

I would think so, but it depends on if he ends up dead in the main novel. If he survives, a "bonus chapter" after the main novel (I wouldn't call it an epilogue) could be "Alfred's Awesome African Adventure" or whatever. Especially if he is off the stage well before the end of the book, and you think readers like him. A good meal warrants a good dessert!

Comment: This character provides well to the plot of the story and encounters the main character once or twice to give off information about the enemy, but I personally like him and would like to expand on his character a little more. So I was just wondering if people would like that as well as I would.

Answer (score 0):

Side stories in novels are actually real things, and I believe from my own writing experience that they are called vignettes.  The only example of that I can find is in the novel *Whirligig* by Paul Fleishman, where the perspective switches to side characters that are somewhat affected by the main character, Brent.  I'm pretty sure that writing about a side character in the same novel is doable, as long as it helps develop some sort of point or gives a better outlook on what happened.

I hope this helps.  Happy experimenting!

Comment: Oh thank you. Now I have motivation to actually write it out!

Comment: "You're welcome."   Believe it or not, it's an actual quote in Ernest Cline's *Armada*.

Comment: What is? the "you're welcome" thing or the answer you said.